# How to use php & nodejs from separate containers

Tags: php, node.js, docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have the following situation:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        links:
            - apache
            - php
            - node
        depends_on:
            - apache
            - php
            - node
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
    apache:
        image: httpd
    php:
        image: php
    node:
        image: node
```

and I also have a **Dockerfile**

```
FROM phusion/baseimage
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yq git curl zip wget curl
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php # error, no PHP exec found
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN npm install -g bower gulp
COPY ./ /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

Now my question is: how could I use PHP & Node, which are installed in separate containers, in this main app Dockerfile? Is that even possible, or do I need to manually install PHP & Node inside my Dockerfile?

Comment: Could you explain me what contains "web" container? is your code for php and node inside?

Comment: that "Dockerfile" is the "web" service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker doesn't work the way you are thinking. This isn't like code inheritance or configuring a single machine with multiple runtime languages. You are configuring multiple virtual machines, each with their own runtime environment.

if you want to run a PHP app, you put that app in the container that has PHP. same with Node.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm kinda new with the docker stuff (started learning just today), so I wasn't really sure about, if something like that was even possible.